# ¿Como puedo bajar la velocidad de la pelota en este juego de PingPong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, game

Necesito que la pelota se desplace mas lento y estaría bueno que pueda acelerar a medida que se desarrolla el juego.

```
    # ATARI GAME
import turtle
import winsound

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Pong by @TokyoEdTech")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

# Score
score_a = 0
score_b = 0

# Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("blue")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0)

# Paddle B
paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_b.speed(0)
paddle_b.shape("square")
paddle_b.color("blue")
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.goto(350, 0)

# Ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("square")
ball.color("white")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.dx = 1
ball.dy = -1

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 260)
pen.write("Player A: 0  PlayerB: 0", align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

# Function
def paddle_a_up():
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y += 20
    paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_a_down():
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y -= 20
    paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_b_up():
    y = paddle_b.ycor()
    y += 20
    paddle_b.sety(y)

def paddle_b_down():
    y = paddle_b.ycor()
    y -= 20
    paddle_b.sety(y)

# Keyboard binding
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, "Up")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, "Down")

# Main game loop
while True:
    wn.update()

    # Move the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    # Border checking
    if ball.ycor() > 290:
        ball.sety(290)
        ball.dy *= -1
        winsound.PlaySound("sound4.mp3", winsound.SND_ASYNC)

    if ball.ycor() < -290:
        ball.sety(-290)
        ball.dy *= -1
        winsound.PlaySound("sound4.mp3", winsound.SND_ASYNC)


    if ball.xcor() > 390:
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1
        score_a += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Player A: {}  PlayerB: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))


    if ball.xcor() < -390:
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1
        score_b += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Player A: {}  PlayerB: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))


    # Paddle and ball collisions
    if (ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.xcor() < 350) and (ball.ycor() < paddle_b.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > paddle_b.ycor() - 40):
        ball.setx(340)
        ball.dx *= -1
        winsound.PlaySound("sound4.mp3", winsound.SND_ASYNC)


    if (ball.xcor() < -340 and ball.xcor() > -350) and (ball.ycor() < paddle_a.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > paddle_a.ycor() - 40):
        ball.setx(-340)
        ball.dx *= -1
        winsound.PlaySound("sound4.mp3", winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

Answer (score 3):

Creo que con simplemente añadir una espera al final del bucle principal podría servir.

Introduce al principio

```
import time
espera = 0.0005
```

y al final del bucle While, pero dentro, mete esto:

```
time.sleep(max(0, espera))
espera -= 0.0000000001
```

Puedes ajustar el tiempo de espera (0.0005) a lo que mejor te encaje. Si lo quieres hacer más rápido, simplemente ve disminuyendo el tiempo de espera con cada ciclo.